# Module wx has no 'Frame' member (python)

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, member

I have a problem while using module wx in python. When I write this simple code

```
import wx

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(parent = None, title = "Hello World")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

the compiler returns me the following error: module wx has no 'Frame' member *pylint(no-member) [4,9]*.

[image]

The window appears but it still gives me this error...

Answer (score 1):

Bisual Basic Code (or VSCodium) does not work well in Linux with wxpython, at the moment (I had the same problem), one can't even import wx alone. although, your code worked perfectly under IDLE.